# jQuery drawing gridlines on element

Tags: jquery, gridlines

I am using a [small](http://jquery.iceburg.net/jqDnR/), but great drag 'n drop and resize plugin for jQuery. I would like to add some gridlines around any element (top, bottom, left and right) that I may drag or resize with this plugin. Does anybody know of a plugin or some code that will help me doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is to modify the plugin to fit your needs. The plugin is adding the .jqHandle based on the function call. You could modify the CSS to instead of being a red box, it could just be the border.

Here's a JS bin to show you: http://jsbin.com/cozotuto/5/edit

The HTML has been modified so that the handle is now the container, and the CSS has been modified. The function call remains the same.

Comment: thanks @bencripps, but it does not seem to be working

Comment: Hmm, if you look at the console, remoteWindow is undefined. If you have the plugin working in your environment it should work fine for you. I have it working locally, but for whatever reason, it's throwing an error in JSbin. http://jsbin.com/cozotuto/6/edit?html,output#J:L1